# d3 parallel coordinates chart y-axis with ticks plotting issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I am trying to reproduce a chart similar to this - 
http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/raw/3150059/

with d3 v4. Here is my fork with updated code - 
    http://bl.ocks.org/iamdeadman/a75c0a97459b131eccbc24e99c340ab8/321e048d287293525a9f23ae276025aa8916f7f6

Because of some incorrect / erroneous change while porting the above block to 
d3 v4 I am seeing the layout now like this -

[image]

i.e. all the axis are moved to left & right positions.

I suspect this is because of incorrect x scale provided to the axis during placement.

So, initially they were initialized like this -

```
xscale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangePoints([0, w], 1),
```

& I changed this to -

```
xscale = d3.scaleOrdinal().range([0, w], 1),
```

After this to extract & create scales for all the dimensions they have done -

```
xscale.domain(dimensions = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(k) {
    return (_.isNumber(data[0][k])) && (yscale[k] = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return +d[k]; }))
      .range([h, 0]));
  }).sort());
```

So now,

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
      .data(dimensions)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "dimension")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log(d, xscale(d));  return "translate(" + xscale(d) + ")"; })
```

So now here for all values of `d` I am getting xscale as `(0 / chart width-1)` response. Not sure why.

Can anyone help finding / figuring out the issue here.